# Conflito FFmpeg rodando em diferentes processos

Tags: node.js, vídeo

Tenho um servidor nodeJS que faz algumas manipulações com arquivos de audio, utilizando a biblioteca fluent-ffmpeg, porem ao concatenar alguns arquivos utilizando a função:

```
    ffmpeg('./public/uploads/'+tmpFilename)
    .input(path+newTmpName)
    .complexFilter([
        'acrossfade=d='+fade+':o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri'
    ])
    .on('end', () =>{

        deleteArray.push(newTmpName);
        deleteArray.push(tmpFilename);

        deleteFiles(deleteArray).then(() =>{
            parentPort.postMessage(newFilename);
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log('erro ao apagar os arquivos temporarios');
            throw new Error(error);
        })

    })
    .on('error', (error) =>{
        console.log('erro na concatenação das partes: '+ error)
        throw new Error(error);
    })
    .saveToFile('./public/uploads/'+newFilename);
```

Funciona tudo certo quando eu rodo uma só instancia, se eu testo com mais usuarios (ou mesmo multiplas abas no mesmo navegador) ele gera com o tempo errado, parecendo que existe um tipo de conflito entre os processos rodando.
Porem em todo lugar que eu procuro, mostram que é possivel se rodar varios processos sem conflito.

Comment: O tmpFilename é garantidamente único? Como você gera ele?

Comment: é concatenado uma string uuid(v4) no final do tmpFilename,  `tmpFilename = 'tmpFile'+counter+uuidv4()+'.wav';`

Comment: O `uuid` não é garantia, dependerá do usuário e situação. Ao invés disto experimente: https://www.npmjs.com/package/temp.